# Can't compare sheetname with string value

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

What i need is to compare or search for a string in a sheet name..

I mean, the excel file might have more than one sheet, but only the sheets with a specific string let said

only sheets named "FORMATO SIVE 04" are going to be processed...

I'm debugging like crazy and I'm getting confused... my code it's like this

```
            Workbook eworkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(Archivo);

            int totalsheet = eworkbook.getNumberOfSheets();

            System.out.println("fuerawhile"+totalsheet);
            sheetName=new String[totalsheet];

            //String nombrehoja = eworkbook.getSheetName(0).toString();                 
            //System.out.println(nombrehoja);

            Sheet sheet = null;

            while(i<totalsheet){
                sheetName[i] = eworkbook.getSheetName(i);
                System.out.println("Antes IF :" + sheetName[i]);
                FORMATO = sheetName[i];
                if(FORMATO == "FORMATO SIVE 04"){
                    flag = true;
                }

                if(flag){
                    System.out.println("dentroIF : " + sheetName[i]);
                    sheet = eworkbook.getSheet(sheetName[i].toString());
                    System.out.println("Exito");
                }
                else if (!flag){
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
                System.out.println("dentrowhile : " + sheetName[i]);
                i++;
            }
```

but it doesnt give me true :( 
[image]

does anybody has any idea?

I think this is too easy but I'm having a lot of time in this and i think I'm right :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't compare `String` values with `==`; use `String`'s `equals` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @rgettman It's the **answer** the duplicate, not the question! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, `String`s should never be compared using `==` (unless you want to test intern logic, maybe). Prefer:

```
if( "FORMATO SIVE 04".equals(FORMATO) ) {
....
```

If you are sure `FORMATO` will never be `null`, you can also use the more legible form:

```
if( FORMATO.equals("FORMATO SIVE 04") ) {
```

Comment: Noticed rgettman's comment too late.  Thanks for your gesture.

Comment: do you know how I can "bump" a question?
I've asked a question and I don't see any move :(

Comment: @Raf0c  Offer a bounty?